# How should I dereference a local variable to get the address of a record element in a TList?

Tags: pointers, delphi, record, dereference, tvirtualstringtree

I am converting a Delphi app from using a TTreeView to using a TVirtualStringTree; The node data is held in TItemData records in a TList.

```
type
  TItemData = record
    idName: string;
  end;
  PItemData = ^TItemData

  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  ...
  private
    itemData: TList<TItemData>;
  ..
  end;
```

I wanted to get the displayed tree up and running in the most straightforward way possible, and then gradually convert the app little by little as I got to understand how to use the VirtualStringTree. So, I have a buildTreeFromItemData() method, which iterates through the TList elements and creates child nodes in the VirtualStringTree. I [tried to] pass a pointer to each TItemData record in each call to VST.addChild() which would then be dereferenced in vstGetText(), something like this:

```
procedure buildTreeFromItemData;
var 
  i:  integer;
  idA: TItemData;
begin
  for i := 0 to itemData.count - 1 do begin
    idA := itemData[i];
    vst.addChild(NIL, @idA);
  end;
end;
```

Dereference the pointer:

```
procedure TMyForm.vstGetData(...);
var
  idB: TItemData;
begin
  idB := node.getData^;
  CellText := idB.idName;
end;
```

It quickly became apparent that no matter how many different ways I tried to code this, e.g. @itemData[i], the only times my code compiled every vst node was actually getting the address of the idA local variable, and every tree node was pointing to the most recent TItemData record pointed to by idA. I was then getting access violations in vstGetText() once buildTreeFromItemData() had completed and the local idA variable went out of scope, i.e. every node's data pointer in vst was now invalid.

Most of my attempts to somehow deference idA and get at the address location of the TItemData stored in idA generated an "invalid typecast" from the Delphi syntax checker, let alone the compiler.

At one point I tried something like this:

```
  ptr1^ := @idA;
```

I have no idea what that actually means to the Delphi compiler. I know what I wanted it to mean: I wanted it to mean "set ptr1 to the [dereferened] address stored at the address of the idA local variable". To my surprise, it compiled but went bang as soon as the debugger hit that statement. (What does the compiler think "ptr1^ := " means?)

Eventually I hit upon the idea of typecasting idA to a TObject; at least then, my thinking went, the compiler would know we were at least in the realms of dereferencing and might actually let me, eventually, get to the pointer I really needed to pass to vst.addChild().

After much experimentation, and many more "invalid typecast"s, unbelievably [at least to me] the following code works!.....

```
procedure buildTreeFromItemData;
var
  i:     integer;
  idA:   TItemData;
  myObj: TObject;
  ptr1:  pointer;
  ptr2:  PItemData;
begin
  for i := 0 to itemData.count - 1 do begin
    idA   := itemData[i];
    myObj := TObject(@idA);
    ptr1  := pointer(myObj)
    ptr2  := PItemData(ptr1^);
    vst.addChild(NIL, ptr2);
  end;
end;
```

ptr2 is now so far removed, syntactically and semantically, from idA, that the compiler *finally* allows the dereference in PItemData(ptr1^), although it only allowed it after I added the PItemData(...) typecast.

I don't even have to dereference this pointer in vstGetText!...

```
procedure TMyForm.vstGetText(...);
var
  idB: PItemData;
begin
  idB := PItemData(node.getData);
  CellText := idB.idName;
end;
```

The tree displays perfectly and the access violations are gone. *(NB. The actual code in buildTreeFromItemData() is a lot more involved and creates child nodes of child nodes to create a complex tree structure several levels deep.)*

Although I eventually found a solution at gone 1am this morning after *a lot* of trial and error, I find it difficult to believe that my jiggerypokery with the local variable is really necessary for something so  simple. So my question is this: what is the correct Delphi syntax for getting the address of my TItemData record stored in a plain "idA: TItemData;" local variable?

*(I think this is my first ever question to stackoverflow; I hope I have formulated it well enough. I've kept the code to the absolute bare bones necessary to illustrate the issue and I wasn't able to completely reproduce the exact experimentation code I went through. The solution in the final two code blocks, though, is my working code. If I can improve how I've formulated the question and the explanation to meet stackoverflow's stringent standards, please let me know.)*

Answer (score 3):

> what is the correct Delphi syntax for getting the address of my TItemData record stored in a plain "idA: TItemData;" local variable?

Well...  That one is simple. You do it like this : `@idA`.

The issue here is that it is NOT what you want to do.  You want to have the address of the `TItemData` in your list (`idA` is merely a copy of the record in `itemData`).

To get the address of a value inside of a `TList<T>`, you can't use `property Items[Index: Integer]: T` of `TList<T>` as it will only return you a copy of the value. You need to use `property List: arrayofT` which will give you direct access the underlying array in which the values are stored, and then you can get the address with : `@itemData.List[I]`.

That being said, it is not something I would recommend.  There is no guarantees how long that pointer will remain valid. There is a lot of operations on the list that might render that address invalid, or make it point to the wrong `TItemData`. If `itemData` is immutable by the time you acquire the pointer, it's should be ok.  Otherwise, it would be way better to allocate new `TItemData` like described by IVO GELOV in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74262971/65863).

Answer to comment :

> is there no legit Delphi syntax to achieve what I managed to do?

You did *not* manage to do what you *think* you did.

```
idA   := itemData[i]; //Copy the value from the list
myObj := TObject(@idA); //Take the address of iDA and pretend it's a TObject
ptr1  := pointer(myObj) //Now, pretend my TObject is a Pointer
ptr2  := PItemData(ptr1^); //Now, pretend ptr1 is pointing to a PItemData.
//I didn't test it, but I'm pretty sure you could have just written `ptr2 := PItemData((@iDA)^)`
vst.addChild(NIL, ptr2);
```

So what does this code do? The "main event" here is `ptr2  := PItemData(ptr1^)`.  It takes the address of `idA`, take the first *PointerSize*(For simplicity, I'll assume 32 bits going forward) byte at that address and pretend it's a `PItemData`. What are the first 32 bit of `TItemData`? A `string`, more precisely `idName`. Maybe it will help you understand to consider that `@idA = @idA.IdName`.

So, in other words, `vst.addChild(NIL, ptr2);` is the same as `vst.addChild(NIL, PChar(idA.idName));` or `vst.addChild(NIL, @idA.idName[1]);` (except for empty string... but I digress). So, what you add in the `vst` is not the address of the record in `itemData`, it's the address of the first character of the string idA.idName.

But, your confusion is probably coming from believing records are reference types.  They are not, they are value types.

Comment: Thanks. You say that idA is merely a copy of the record in itemData and yet, by a very roundabout way, I was able to get to the actual pointer in the TList, so is that actually true? Surely, idA must be holding a copy of the *pointer* in the TList, no ?. Using typical Delphi code, @ idA only ever gave me the address of the local variable, as one would expect. When idA was set to another element in the TList, every node pointed to that element too, since they were all holding @ idA. Noting all the possible pitfalls to such code, is there no legit Delphi syntax to achieve what I managed to do?

Comment: You did not do what you think you did. Check my edit.

Comment: So the fact that the tree appeared (at least superficially) to be working, displaying all the correct node captions throughout from vst.getText, was I really just keeping each occurrence of the idA.idName strings alive through reference counting?

Comment: @BazCuda The string in the vst were most likely kept alive by the TItemData in itemData. And yes, strings are reference counted. But for reference counting to work, it needs to be of type `string`. So the pointer you pass to vst.addChild doesn't count as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of TVirtualTree is to store your data inside the nodes. TVirtualTree will reserve memory for your data and that's why you need to tell the tree how big is your data.
So, when your form is created (inside OnCreate handler) you should set the `NodeDataSize` property of your VirtualTree:

```pascal
procedure TmyForm.TntFormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  myVirtualTree.NodeDataSize:=SizeOf(TItemData);
end;
```

You should also handle the OnFreeNode event from your VirtualTree:

```pascal
procedure TmyForm.myVirtualTreeFreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  Data:PItemData;
begin
  Data:=Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  if Assigned(Data) then Finalize(Data^);
end;
```

When you want to create a new node in the tree:

```pascal
procedure TmyForm.CreateNewNode(data:TItemData);
var
  node: PItemData;
  P: PVirtualNode;
begin
  with myVirtualTree do
  begin
    P:=AddChild(Nil);
    node:=GetNodeData(P);
    node^:=data;
    // ReinitNode is very important - to update InternalNode precomputed
    // text width. Otherwise node can not be properly selected if
    // FullRowSelect is FALSE
    ReinitNode(P,False);
  end;
end;
```

You will also need to handle other events from TVirtualTree like OnGetText, onPaintText, onCompareNodes, onIncrementalSearch, onDblClick, onGetHint, etc.

Comment: Hi, yes I have now properly virtualized all my node data, thanks. However, that doesn't answer the original question which wasn't directly related to TVirtualStringTree per se; the issue simply cropped up in that particular code.  My question is how to get Delphi to [properly] give me the actual location address of a record in a TList identified by a local variable without all the millarky that I went through conning the compiler into dereferencing the local variable., e.g. the address in (not of) myRec, when var myRec: TMyRecord;

Comment: if you have a procedure/function argument that is marked with the `var` keyword - the compiler takes care of all the dereferencing. If you have a local variable of type `record` (like TMyRecord) - the compiler stores this variable on the stack so `@myRec` is the address inside the stack. However, TList can not hold records - it can only hold Pointers. So it's your job and responsibility to GetMem for your data and save the pointer to that memory fragment into TList. And then FreeMem when it is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I realize that that's the correct way to do it, I was just surprised that there seemed to be no legitimate way of getting Delphi to give me the pointer stored in the local variable when it's a record. If I was programming in C, it would be a doddle. Maybe I could have passed idA as a parameter to a function, and got to the pointer that way? Presumably, the compiler would still have tried to second-guess me :D

Comment: Your example record has just one member and it is a String. So, if you need the address of the first symbol in that String - then you can take it as `@idA.idName[0]` or `PAnsiChar(idA.idName)`. If your local variable is a pointer to something - you don't need to dereference at all, as it is already a pointer. You may only need to type-cast that pointer.

Comment: Thanks. As Ken Bourassa has identified, my fundamental misunderstanding stems from the fact that I was viewing records as reference types when they're value types. One of the pitfalls, possibly, of [me] regularly switching between C and Delphi.

Comment: Are not records in C value types, too? I believe that your confusion comes from the fact that in Delphi objects/classes are usually named with T even though they are actually pointers since Delphi 2 (the new "class" objects use dynamic memory while the old "object" objects use static memory). So a variable of type TList is actually of type PList (^TList) but Delphi conveniently hides this from you. However, a variable of type TItemData is not a pointer - it is the actual record.